# suspicious ip attempt to connect server

Tags: networking, security, ufw

I'm getting message 
`suspicious ip [x.x.x.x] attempt to connect server`
What action I have to take for this issue? The affected server is Ubuntu 14.04 server
and has `ufw` and a public IP.

ufw log:

```
Nov  3 12:12:55  kernel: [358619.800870] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:24:14:33:18:01:08:00 SRC=37.139.191.161 DST=10.0.0.12 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=44 ID=8329 PROTO=TCP SPT=43730 DPT=23 WINDOW=23100 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  3 12:14:08  kernel: [358692.822316] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:24:14:33:18:01:08:00 SRC=122.114.182.64 DST=10.0.0.12 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=233 ID=48132 PROTO=TCP SPT=54910 DPT=1433 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  3 12:14:11  kernel: [358696.027769] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:24:14:33:18:01:08:00 SRC=89.248.172.16 DST=10.0.0.12 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=52590 PROTO=TCP SPT=46640 DPT=8009 WINDOW=62657 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  3 12:14:43  kernel: [358727.590448] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:24:14:33:18:01:08:00 SRC=123.249.3.172 DST=10.0.0.12 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=107 ID=256 PROTO=TCP SPT=37365 DPT=8080 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  3 12:14:45  kernel: [358729.683181] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:24:14:33:18:01:08:00 SRC=218.29.142.44 DST=10.0.0.12 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=234 ID=44905 PROTO=TCP SPT=50889 DPT=1433 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  3 12:16:01  kernel: [358806.142162] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:24:14:33:18:01:08:00 SRC=176.109.226.160 DST=10.0.0.12 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=8329 PROTO=TCP SPT=43730 DPT=23 WINDOW=23100 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  3 12:16:24  kernel: [358829.214991] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:24:14:33:18:01:08:00 SRC=212.142.159.191 DST=10.0.0.12 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=35874 PROTO=TCP SPT=13461 DPT=23 WINDOW=9861 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  3 12:17:16  kernel: [358881.046988] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:24:14:33:18:01:08:00 SRC=45.55.29.228 DST=10.0.0.12 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=238 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=57539 DPT=3306 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

auth.log

/var/log$ tailf auth.log

```
Nov  3 12:47:55  sshd[10102]: Failed password for root from 58.218.198.146 port 50077 ssh2
Nov  3 12:48:00  sshd[10102]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 58.218.198.146 port 50077 ssh2]
Nov  3 12:48:01  sshd[10102]: Received disconnect from 58.218.198.146: 11:  [preauth]
Nov  3 12:48:01  sshd[10102]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.218.198.146  user=root
Nov  3 12:48:17  sshd[10104]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.218.198.146  user=root
Nov  3 12:48:19  sshd[10104]: Failed password for root from 58.218.198.146 port 27919 ssh2
Nov  3 12:48:24  sshd[10104]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 58.218.198.146 port 27919 ssh2]
Nov  3 12:48:24  sshd[10104]: Received disconnect from 58.218.198.146: 11:  [preauth]
Nov  3 12:48:24  sshd[10104]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.218.198.146  user=root
Nov  3 12:48:37  sshd[10108]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.218.198.146  user=root
Nov  3 12:48:39  sshd[10108]: Failed password for root from 58.218.198.146 port 43229 ssh2
Nov  3 12:48:43  sshd[10108]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 58.218.198.146 port 43229 ssh2]
Nov  3 12:48:43  sshd[10108]: Received disconnect from 58.218.198.146: 11:  [preauth]
Nov  3 12:48:43  sshd[10108]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.218.198.146  user=root
```

Comment: For me, that's not enough information from the logs to make an assessment of how to address it.  At least 10 lines from your logs would help... maybe 5 to seven lines before the entry and 5 to seven lines after the entry.  Basically, you're most likely just looking at noise (info FYI) in the log and it could probably be ignored.  Public IP's are always being scanned, sometimes innocently possibly verifying access to or security of their own block of IP's, and often sinister people looking for vulnerabilities to exploit.

Comment: You can use something like Fail2ban for more security, after X attempts the source IP is blocked for X time.

Comment: fail2ban is good idea @sys0dm1n

is there anything else which we can do,

Comment: You will see such attempts on your ssh server they are scripted attacks. Disable password authentication, dont allow root login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are automated attempts to crack into your ssh server and very common.

IMO the most important actions for you to take are:

1. Only allow ssh login via keys, disable passwords.
2. Do not allow root to login.

You do not need to install any additional services, you can take care of this problem with iptables.

First install iptables-persistent

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

then

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource

sudo iptables -A INPUT -m recent --update --rchedk --seconds 600 --hitcount 8 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

"--hit count" is the number of new connections. Keep in mind each new connection gives multiple opportunities to enter a password. If you use scp, use a higher hitcount as each file will be a new ssh session.

"--seconds" How long an ipaddress will be blacklisted. 10 minutes is usually sufficient to deter most "script kiddies".

For additional information / suggestions see http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_security

Comment: In the past couple of years I've noticed: 10 minutes is no longer enough, often they keep returning after a hour or hours; Often (China in particular) they just switch to another source IP address in the same sub-net and continue. So, I use 1 day ban time now, and an arbitrary, but largish, sub-net mask for the addresses table.

Comment: @DougSmythies Good point. They are not getting into my ssh server with their scripts, I grep the logs and add the user names they use to Deny.